# Execute certain Examples from Scenario Outlines

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

I have to execute certain `Examples` from `Scenario Outlines`.

Let's see the following example:

```
Feature: Temp

Scenario Outline: Test.Something.On.<environment>
  When action is performed on "<environment>"

Examples:
 |environment|
 |lab        |
 |prod       |
```

I would like to execute only the example with `lab` from the upper presented `Examples`.

I tried the followings:

- *Filter by line number*: `mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/features/Temp.feature:8"` - this way only the lab scenario was executed, however this is not a long term solution;
- *Filter by name*: `mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="name lab"` - it works for `Scenario` but not for `Scenario Outline` even if the name of the scenario will be `Test.Something.On.lab`;
- *decompose* the `Scenario Outline` in `Scenarios` and tag the proper scenarios with `@lab` and `@prod` - I hate code duplication and the subsequent maintenance, therefore I hope there is an another solution for this.

Any suggestions?
Big thanks.

Another sub-keywords: `maven`, `java`, `cucumber-java8`, `cucumber-junit`, `junit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two examples in yoour scenario outline and tag each example in a similar way as you have done in your third option. That should give you the behaviour you are asking for.